# Get saved content of entry

Tags: plugin-development, events

I hooked up into the `content.saveContent` event. I want to save the entry content into a different application. Is there a way to retrieve the content as a Json (Or something more friendly). I think do `$event->params['content']->title` is now the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$event->params['content]` will return a [ContentModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ContentModel) object.

You can either access specific fields directly, like you found, or loop through them all with `->getAttributes()` grabbing the ones you want to save externally.